# Date to SQLDate

Tags: java

I have a simple function converts `date` to `java.sql.date`.

```
public static java.sql.Date getSqlDate(String dateStr, String format) {
    java.sql.Date dt = null;
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    date = df.parse(dateStr, pos);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    dt = java.sql.Date.valueOf(cal.get(cal.YEAR) + "-" + (cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1)
            + "-" + cal.get(cal.DATE));
    return dt;
}
```

The problem is when i call this function with the following i'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException`.

"2008-02-04", "yyyy-dd-MM"

May be I'm not able to catch error in the code, hence wanted to have another set of eyes looking into this and correct me please...

-- M

Comment: you should switch cal.get(cal.MONTH) and cal.get(cal.DATE) at the second line from the bottom, assigning to dt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
java.util.Date dt = null;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
date = df.parse(dateStr, pos);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but unable to get the reason why valueOf was not working for me. I also tried with input format as "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 1):

should it not be:

```
dt = java.sql.Date.valueOf(cal.get(cal.YEAR) + "-" + cal.get(cal.DATE)  + "-" +(cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1));
```

to agree with the yyyy-dd-mm format, as your code examples shows a yyyy-mm-dd format:

```
cal.get(cal.YEAR) + "-" + (cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(cal.DATE)
```